# How to build Static Binary for Tesseract?

Tags: c++, tesseract

I am currently building Tesseract 4.0.0 from source (on Ubuntu 14.04 for context), using the instructions found on: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling

I am using the following ./configure parameters:

`./configure --disable-openmp  --disable-graphics --disable-opencl --enable-static LDFLAGS='-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++' --disable-shared`

Followed by 
`make` and `sudo make install`

The compiled binary I am running after is `src/api/tesseract`, which works as intended. The problem is that when I run ldd on this file, it actually shows dependencies.

Am I looking in the wrong spot for the static binary of Tesseract (I ran a find command in the entire repo and didn't see anything else that looked like an executable), or am I misunderstanding the meaning of a static binary - I am under the impression it is pretty much an executable version of Tesseract that does not require any dependencies to be pre installed.

If there is any problem with the configure options too please let me know. I do not believe that `--disable-openmp  --disable-graphics --disable-opencl` impacts static vs shared linking but I am using those for my desired tesseract build so I included them for more context.

Comment: Try using vcpkg for auto installation, recently given multi-platform support.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm also looking for at static binary which is portable without any dependencies

Answer (score 0):

$ uname -a

> Linux vm00 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:46:08 UTC
> 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ echo $CFLAGS

> -static

$ echo $LDFLAGS

> -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

$ ./configure --enable-static LDFLAGS='-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++' --disable-shared

> ...
>
> Configuration is done.

$ make

> ...
>
> Making all in unittest
>
> ...

$ **file src/api/tesseract**

> src/api/tesseract: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1
> (GNU/Linux), ***dynamically linked***, interpreter /lib64/l, for
> GNU/Linux 3.2.0,
> BuildID[sha1]=96afb1f1ff8962b3f9046c40407364ebf26369d1, with
> debug_info, not stripped

Not *statically linked*.